# How to enable horizontal scroll of ListView within modalBottomSheet?

Tags: flutter

EDIT: Issue was local with emulator, code works as expected.

I have a `showBottomModalSheet` which should contain some widgets as well as `ListView` with some `Container` which should be horizontally scrollable. May I ask if somebody was able to resolve something like that? I was trying different attributes, but nothing seems to work for me.

Here is dummy code to replicate my issue:

Btn to display bottom modal:

```dart
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return _buildBottomWidget();
      });
    },
  ),
```

And here is my widget build:

```dart
Widget _buildBottomWidget() {
  return Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text('Header'),
        SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 10,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Index $index'),
                        Text('Description for index $index'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I am trying to be able to scroll that items in `ListView` inside that modal. Can somebody give me an advice how to achieve it?

Comment: Is it not scrollable with this code?

Comment: I tried your code, ListView is scrolling fine. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not scrollable for me (using Flutter 3.7). It is inside Scaffold as a body and when it is inside that bottom modal, for some reason only dragging modal works, but scroll that items does not.

Comment: Found an issue. Code works as expected. Found out that after using emulator, it works as expected. Not sure what was wrong since I did not change anything on code side.